# Separate plain filenames from fnmatch patterns in python

Tags: python, glob, fnmatch

My python function is given a (long) list of path arguments, each of which can possibly be a glob. I make a pass over this list using `glob.glob` to extract all the matching filenames, like this:

```
files  = [filename for pattern in patterns for filename in glob.glob(pattern)]
```

That works, but the filesystem I'm on has very poor performance for directory listing operations, and currently this operation adds about a minute(!) to the start-up time of my program. So I would like to only perform glob expansion for non-trivial glob patterns (i.e. those that aren't just normal pathnames) to speed this up. I.e.

```
def cheapglob(pattern):
    return [pattern] if istrivial(pattern) else glob.glob(pattern)
files  = [filename for pattern in patterns for filename in cheapglob(pattern)]
```

Since `glob.glob` basically does a set of directory listings coupled with `fnmatch.fnmatch`, I thought it should be possible to somehow ask `fnmatch` whether a given string is a non-trivial pattern or not, but I can't see how to do that.

As a fallback, I guess I could attempt to identify these patterns in the string myself, though that feels a lot like reinventing the wheel, and would be error prone. But this feels like the sort of thing there should be an elegant solution for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the fnmatch source code](http://code.google.com/p/unladen-swallow/source/browse/trunk/Lib/fnmatch.py), the only special characters it recognizes are `*`, `?`, `[` and `]`. Hence any pattern that does not contain any of these will only match itself. We can therefore implement the `cheapglob` mentioned in the question as

```
def cheapglob(s): return glob.glob(s) if re.search("[][*?]", s) else [s]
```

This will only hit the file system for patterns which include special characters. This differs subtly from a plain `glob.glob`: For a pattern with no special characters like "foo.txt", this function will return `["foo.txt"]` regardless of whether that file exists, while `glob.glob` will return `[]` if the file isn't there. So the calling function will need to handle the possibility that some of the returned files might not exist.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you'll find much, as your idea of a trivial pattern might not be mine. Also, from a comp-sci point of view, it might be impossible to tell from inspection whether a pushdown automata is going to run in a set amount of time given the inputs you're running it against, without actually running it against those inputs.

I strongly suspect you'd be better off here loading the directory listing once and then applying `fnmatch` against that list manually.

Comment: How about "a pattern with no characters that `fnmatch` recognizes as special", then? Those would only match themselves. That is a well-defined problem.

I don't have only a single directory that I could list once and for all. That would not be a problem. Each directory is already being listed only once each in the 1 minute running time I mentioned in the question. There are just many of them, and each listing is slow.